# How can I create a single column for duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have a table looking like this (>200 readings, duplicate samples):

```
          **A    B   C**
 Site1      1    2   3
 Site1      4    5   6
 Site2      7    8   9
 Site2      10   11  12
```

What code can be used to get output of:

```
    **X**
    1
    4
    2
    5
    3
    6
    7
    10
    8
    11
    9
    12
```

Comment: you can do `data.frame(X=unlist(split(m1, row.names(m1)), use.names = FALSE))`

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dataset is a `matrix` (as `data.frame` cannot have duplicate row names), `split` by the rownames and `unlist` the `list`

```
data.frame(X=unlist(split(m1, row.names(m1)), use.names = FALSE))
#    X
#1   1
#2   4
#3   2
#4   5
#5   3
#6   6
#7   7
#8  10
#9   8
#10 11
#11  9
#12 12
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 12L
), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Site1", "Site1", "Site2", 
 "Site2"), c("A", "B", "C")))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. However, the data.frame that I am getting is not what I was looking for. I would like to have a 1 column with the duplicates in order (per site)1,4,2,5,3,etc.... with your code I am getting a 1,2,3,4,..
I am very naive with this stuff yet. Maybe I am missing something..

Comment: @VictorCP  As I mentioned in the post, I am using example and i assumed it as a matrix

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your dataset is a data frame, you can consider using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Notice that data frame cannot have duplicated row names, so I assume that there is a column called `Site` documented if the record is `Site1` or `Site2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Site    A    B   C
 Site1      1    2   3
 Site1      4    5   6
 Site2      7    8   9
 Site2      10   11  12",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt
#    Site  A  B  C
# 1 Site1  1  2  3
# 2 Site1  4  5  6
# 3 Site2  7  8  9
# 4 Site2 10 11 12

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Col, X, -Site) %>%
  arrange(Site) %>%
  select(X)
dt2
#     X
# 1   1
# 2   4
# 3   2
# 4   5
# 5   3
# 6   6
# 7   7
# 8  10
# 9   8
# 10 11
# 11  9
# 12 12
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you have (let's call it `data`) is of class `matrix` then you can use the following function:

```
X <- as.vector(t(data))
```

If it is a `data.frame` transform it into a matrix, because I see that all your entries are numbers.